# How to add new lines between sublists?

Tags: python, formatting

I have a function that is currently returning this:

`[['o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o'], ['o', 'o', 'X', 'o', 'o'], ['o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o'], ['o', '_', 'o', 'o', 'o'], ['o', 'o', '_', 'o', 'o']]`

when I would instead like it to return:

```
[['o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o'], 
 ['o', 'o', 'X', 'o', 'o'], 
 ['o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o'], 
 ['o', '_', 'o', 'o', 'o'], 
 ['o', 'o', '_', 'o', 'o']]
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
def create_box(box):
    for i in box:
       line = []
        for j in box:
            letters = []
            for k in j:
                if k != " ":
                    letters.append(k)
            line.append(letters)
            output = "\n".join(str(line))

    return line
```

The input value is from a text file. It is this:

```
o o o o o
o o X o o
o o o o o
o _ o o o
o o _ o o
```

How would I go about adding a new line in between the sublists?

Comment: Inside your function, you do a bunch of work to create a string called `output` that has some newlines in it, but then you `return battleship_line`, which is apparently a global variable (since there isn't any other code in the function that deals with it). Is that what you wanted to happen?

Comment: Why are you iterating through `box` twice?

Comment: So you only wan't to print that list differently?

Comment: Yes, I want to print a list of lists from the input value. With new lines between each sub-list.

Comment: This is a strange use of the `line` variable... For each item in `box` you reinstate the list... You could do 1 loop while declaring `line` outside of the loop and remove the double loop... Plus the join isn't a list, at the time you call `output = "\n".join(str(line))` you are making a string variable, which is partly why it is printed that way

Comment: Um, those two lists [are exactly identical](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P7m0qCg1r0TBViE6Wj1fXUcBk4jVUUCWisAthV1XPAEDkeVjY7lSUoszi1JTCLiIC5@buBSI0RlP0Fg0lxUUZeaVaMBDzFYB6lTN//8B).

Comment: The second one (the one I am aiming for), has a new line in between each sublist.

Answer (score 1):

Python has a built-in module called [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) (for pretty-print) that does this sort of thing out-of-the-box:

```
import pprint

s = [['o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o'], ['o', 'o', 'X', 'o', 'o'], ['o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o'], ['o', '_', 'o', 'o', 'o'], ['o', 'o', '_', 'o', 'o']]

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter()
pp.pprint(s)
```

result:

```
[['o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o'],
 ['o', 'o', 'X', 'o', 'o'],
 ['o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o'],
 ['o', '_', 'o', 'o', 'o'],
 ['o', 'o', '_', 'o', 'o']]
```

---

**Edit based on requirements**

To do something like this manually, you can `join` the string representations of the lists with a comma and new line (and a space to make it line up). You will need to add the outside brackets manually. The important part is calling `str()` on each sublist to get a string from the list:

```
s = [['o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o'], ['o', 'o', 'X', 'o', 'o'], ['o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o'], ['o', '_', 'o', 'o', 'o'], ['o', 'o', '_', 'o', 'o']]

print('['+ ',\n '.join(str(sub) for sub in s) + ']')
```

Resulting in:

```
[['o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o'],
 ['o', 'o', 'X', 'o', 'o'],
 ['o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o'],
 ['o', '_', 'o', 'o', 'o'],
 ['o', 'o', '_', 'o', 'o']]
```

Comment: This is very helpful. Would it be possible to implement this manually, though? I'm trying to avoid importing anything.

Comment: @AnthonyPetruzzio respectfully, avoiding importing things that are part of the standard library is not a great use of python. Just because it is imported doesn't mean it's not Python. A *lot* of useful tools are put into the library and it makes no sense to reinvent them. Things like `itertools` and `collections` and very much a part of basic python, but you need to import them to use them.

Comment: I understand, and I agree. I would use import, but this is for an assignment and we were given instructions to do this manually. Thank you for your help though I appreciate it!

Comment: @AnthonyPetruzzio got it. Maybe the edit will point you in a useful direction.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it:

```
output = "["
for sublist in list:
    output += str(sublist) + ',\n '
print(output[:-3] + ']')
```

first collect all sublists in `output` and concat `,\n`  to them and then print it out by removing last 3 chars (`','`, `'\n'`, `' '` ) from it and appending `]`